# How to use ContactDate from ImportantDates

Tags: c#, windows, modern-ui, contactpicker

I try to get birthdate of a contact in a windows store apps. I get always the same wrong date (year 4, month 5 and day 5). Someone try it?

```
var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
var selectedContact = await contactPicker.PickContactAsync();
var birthDate = selectedContact.ImportantDates.FirstOrDefault(@d => @d.Kind == ContactDateKind.Anniversary || @d.Kind == ContactDateKind.Birthday);
if (birthDate != null)
    // always 4-5-5
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}-{1}-{2}", birthDate.Year, birthDate.Month, birthDate.Day);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

For me this here is working:

```
var birthday = selectedContact.ImportantDates.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Kind == ContactDateKind.Birthday);
```